# how to fix this my following code is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I am trying to post a data and trying to return from controller to back again and show it to alert box but dont know why this is not working

here is the controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult getRequirmentsByProject(string projectname)
        {

            return Json(projectname, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and here is my front end code

`<input id="projName" type="text" name="Name" required="" value="javascript">`

and this is my script code

```
 var projectname = document.getElementById('projName').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Worksheet/getRequirmentsByProject',
        type: 'post',
        data: { projectname },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (html) {
            alert(html);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $(that).remove();
            DisplayError(error.statusText);
        }
            });
```

Comment: What exactly isnt working?

Comment: `[HttpPost]` and `Json(projectname, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` part is kind of confusing.

Comment: may i try with httpget?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

its httpget and writing with a wrong way

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult getRequirmentsByProject(string projectname)
        {

            return Json(projectname, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is the right way thankyou for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I am giving you a simple example on how you can `POST` your form variables to your controller using AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var projectname = document.getElementById('projName').value;

  var json = {
              projectname: projectname
             };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getRequirmentsByProject", "Worksheet")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { "json": JSON.stringify(json)},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            $(that).remove();
            DisplayError(error.statusText);
        }
      });

</script>
```

And in your controller, you can get this value as:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getRequirmentsByProject(string json)
{

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic jsondata = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));

        //Get your variables here from AJAX call
        string projectname= jsondata["projectname"];    

    return Json(projectname);
}
```